# schedule python script to run at specific time from monday to friday

Tags: python, python-schedule

i am trying to execute python script at 09:20 am from monday to friday but its not working

```
def job():
    now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
    print(f"Today is: {now.strftime('%A')}")
    if now.weekday() < 5: # Check if today is a weekday
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
        if current_time >= "09:25":
            execute_strategy()
        else:
            print("Not yet time for market open today")
    else:
        print("Today is not a trading day")

# Schedule jobs for every weekday at 09:20 IST
schedule.every().monday.at("09:20").do(job, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
schedule.every().tuesday.at("09:20").do(job, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
schedule.every().wednesday.at("09:20").do(job, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
schedule.every().thursday.at("09:20").do(job, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
schedule.every().friday.at("09:20").do(job, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(60) # Changed the sleep time to 60 seconds to reduce CPU usage
```

i dont know what is wrong here .. my code will not execute

Run the code everyday at 9:20
if possible i want to add
this dates as holidays too
25-Mar-2024, 29-Mar-2024,11-Apr-2024,17-Apr-2024,01-May-2024,17-Jun-2024,17-Jul-2024,15-Aug-2024,02-Oct-2024,01-Nov-2024,15-Nov-2024,25-Dec-2024

```
New code
```

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz
import time
from scheduler import Scheduler
from scheduler.trigger import Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday 

def foo():
    print("foo")

ist = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
schedule = Scheduler(tzinfo=ist)

trigger_time = dt.time(hour=22, minute=52, tzinfo=ist)
schedule.weekly(Monday(trigger_time), foo)
schedule.weekly(Tuesday(trigger_time), foo)
schedule.weekly(Wednesday(trigger_time), foo)
schedule.weekly(Thursday(trigger_time), foo)
schedule.weekly(Friday(trigger_time), foo)

while True:
    schedule.exec_jobs()
    time.sleep(60)
```

add holiday to the new code please

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: i am running window 11

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry.  Perhaps have a look at letting Task Scheduler run the script on a schedule for you.  Here's the [first link](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/execute-python-windows-task-scheduler) that popped up on the subject.  Here is the [search query](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=win+11+task+scheduler+%2B+python&ia=web).

Comment: this is just for development , m going to deploy on cloud

Comment: This is what Task Scheduler is for. Just make a task and tell it when to run what, on what schedule. Don't make Python do this: Windows reboots. A lot. Python should be running "to do the work", not "to monitor whether it's time to do the work" =)

Comment: Generally, even in cloud deployments, you should be able to schedule tasks.  If you end upon a Linux server, `cron` or `systemd` are options for scheduling jobs.  Or use Task Scheduler for Windoze - even in the cloud.

Comment: Agreed. Use cron, task scheduler, etc. Don't reinvent the wheel, the built in OS schedulers will be far more robust